# Semantic equivalent of async for

Tags: python, python-asyncio

From the docs relative to `async for` syntax in Python 3.5, I gathered that it was introduced to iterate over an awaitable iterator.

There is something I don't get in the semantic equivalent that follow the description though:

```
iter = (ITER)
iter = type(iter).__aiter__(iter)
running = True
while running:
    try:
        TARGET = await type(iter).__anext__(iter)
    except StopAsyncIteration:
        running = False
    else:
       BLOCK
else:
    BLOCK2
```

What is the line `iter = type(iter).__aiter__(iter)` doing? Why is it necessary?

Comment: Related: [iterable vs iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magic methods in python, e.g. `__add__`, are *always* [looked up on the class](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=data%20model#special-method-lookup). For example, `len(foo)` will actually <strike>call</strike> resolve to `type(foo).__len__(foo)`. This means it will *never* use a `foo.__len__` if `__len__` is defined on `foo`.

Since `__aiter__`  is a magic method, it is thus always looked up as `type(foo).__aiter__(foo)`.

---

Example for lookup:

```
class Thingy(object):
  def __len__(self):
    return 10

lengthy_thingy = Thingy()
lengthy_thingy.__len__ = lambda self: 20

print(len(lengthy_thingy))  # gives `10`
print(lengthy_thingy.__len__(lengthy_thingy))  # gives `20` instead
print(type(lengthy_thingy).__len__(lengthy_thingy))  # gives `10` as for using `len`
```