# Why doesn't this python assignment work as obviously expected?

Tags: python-3.x

This returns what you'd expect:

```
class My(object):
    def __len__(self):
        return 6

a = My()
print(len(a))
```

But this throws an error:

```
class My2(object):
    pass

b = My2()
b.__len__ = lambda x: 6
print(len(b))
```

`TypeError: object of type 'My2' has no len()`

Why?

Comment: @DanFarrell "Because a lambda isn't a function?" Is that a question or a statement?

Comment: @DanFarrell Lambdas are functions, as you can check from `callable(lambda x: x)` returning `True`. And next time maybe you'll want to avoid ending your statements with question marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are trying to define the method on the instance not on the underlying class. For example, this would work:

```
class My2(object):
    pass

b = My2()
b.__class__.__len__ = lambda x: 6
print(len(b))  # Prints 6
```

Furthermore to clarify the comments, it is not a matter of it being a lambda or a function as proven by this not working:

```
class My2(object):
    pass


def l(x):
    return 6

b = My2()
b.__len__ = l
print(len(b))  # TypeError: object of type 'My2' has no len()
```

Comment: There is a typo in the first code block: `b.__class__.__len__ = lambda x: 6`

Comment: Thanks @JacquesGaudin I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Python `len(a)` as other "magic" functions, is a shorthand for `type(a).__len__(a)`.

Therefore the function (as opposed to method) `__len__` you define on the instance `b` cannot be accessed through `len` since the call would be resolved as:

```
type(b).__len__(b)
```

But `type(b)` doesn't have a method `__len__`.

I asked a similar question and got a very good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38102547/1388292)

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=data%20model#special-method-lookup) is worth reading. Your example is almost identical.