# Why can I reassign dict.update but not dict.__setitem__

Tags: python

I'm trying to modify a third-party `dict` class to make it immutable after a certain point.
With most classes, I can assign to method slots to modify behavior.
However, this doesn't seem possible with all methods in all classes. In particular for `dict`, I can reassign `update`, but not `__setitem__`.

Why? How are they different?

For example:

```
class Freezable(object):
    def _not_modifiable(self, *args, **kw):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def freeze(self):
        """
        Disallow mutating methods from now on.
        """
        print "FREEZE"
        self.__setitem__ = self._not_modifiable
        self.update = self._not_modifiable
        # ... others
        return self

class MyDict(dict, Freezable):
    pass

d = MyDict()
d.freeze()
print d.__setitem__  # <bound method MyDict._not_modifiable of {}>

d[2] = 3         # no error  -- this is incorrect.

d.update({4:5})  # raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: `__setitem__` is a "special" method and is looked up using the class of `self`, not in the instance's `__dict__`.

Comment: Why isn’t update the same?

Comment: `update` doesn't begin and end with double underscores (aka "dunder"), so no, it's not "special". Here's [something about them](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) in the documentation — notice there's no `update` — also see "special method" in the [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html).

Comment: You may be interested in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915937/why-doesnt-this-python-assignment-work-as-obviously-expected/47916260#47916260

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you *can* define the *class* `__setitem__`, e.g.:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if self.update is Freezable._not_modifiable:
        raise TypeError('{} has been frozen'.format(id(self)))
    dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```

(This method is a bit clumsy; there are other options.  But it's one way to make it work even though Python calls the class's `__setitem__` directly.)

Comment: Thank you -- seems like a good solution. I was hoping to replace the method because the original has a particularly efficient machine code implementation -- gains that are lost with wrapping the method. If there's another solution, I'd prefer that.

Comment: Consider: `def __setitem__(self, key, value): self.setitem(self, key, value)` which means you can then `def setitem` in the usual way *and* use your existing trick, just as you do for `update`.

Comment: I think that still leaves `x[..] = y` with the original behavior.

Comment: Try it out. Define `__setitem__` in the class to call some function `f`. Have `f` print that it's called and call `dict.__setitem__` as above. Then set `self.f = self._not_modifiable` as you do above. Then invoke `x[key] = y`.